# Where can I find graphics to use in printable worksheets I create and make available for download?

Tags: images, copyright, graphics

I'm looking to put up a website with worksheets that I make and they will need to have graphics in them.  The worksheets will be available for download for free.  Where can I find images that I can use in these worksheets without infringing on copyrights?  I'm not sure I can just use free clipart.

Comment: What kind of graphics u are looking for? Textures, people, abstract.. some more information would be helpful.

Comment: This kind of question is better off in [chat]

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/) and see if that may apply and work for you. You can also check out the [Crystal Clear Icon](http://www.everaldo.com/crystal/) set. Here is the [license](http://www.everaldo.com/crystal/?action=license) to determine if it will work for you.